# Get numbers from array(Lat Long ) in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string, numbers

I am receiving an array with strings of Lat/Long in PHP from android like this:

```
$array = array(
"parametros1" =>"lat/lng: (-33.36808,-70.74779)",
"parametros2" =>"lat/lng: (-33.36826,-70.74685)",
"parametros3" =>"lat/lng: (-33.36867,-70.745)",
"parametros4" =>"lat/lng: (-33.36875,-70.74462)",
"parametros5" =>"lat/lng: (-33.36879,-70.74436)",
"parametros6" =>"lat/lng: (-33.36882,-70.74415)",
"parametros7" =>"lat/lng: (-33.36888,-70.74387)",
"parametros8" =>"lat/lng: (-33.36905,-70.74364)",
"parametros9" =>"lat/lng: (-33.3691,-70.74347)",
"parametros10"=>"lat/lng: (-33.36948,-70.7417)" 
);
```

And I want to store the values of Lat/lng in 2 arrays, how can I get the values separately ?

Ps:Sorry for my bad english,Thanks.-

Comment: what do you mean? Lat in 1 array and lng in another?

Comment: Yes, 2 array (1 lat , 1 lng) or also 1 array with 2 subarrays(1 lat , 1 lng).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is gonna get a little convoluted, and thats cause some data processing is needed.

```
$lat = array(); 
$lon = array(); 

foreach($array as $k => $v){
 $v = str_replace('lat/lng: (','',$v);
 $v = str_replace(')','',$v);
 $v = explode(',', $v);
 $lat[] = $v[0];
 $lon[] = $v[1];
}

print_r($lat);
print_r($lon);
```

Comment: I love data processing :P enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

Use `list` to map the results of `explode` on `preg_replace` -> `$latLng` to 2 arrays.

```
foreach($array as $key => $latLng){
    list($arrayLat[],$arrayLng[]) = explode(",", preg_replace('/[^-\d.,]/', '', $latLng));
}
```

---

[Ideone Demo 2](http://ideone.com/bVqTpt)

Comment: preg_match is slow. its true. (sometime needed)

Comment: this may not be received well, BUT do some speed checks on regex, its one of those powerful things you only use if you HAVE TO.

Comment: Accepted answer: `OK (0.012 sec real, 0.015 sec wall, 14 MB, 227 syscalls)`  https://eval.in/571668
My first Solution:
`OK (0.008 sec real, 0.010 sec wall, 14 MB, 227 syscalls)`https://eval.in/571670

My second solution:
`OK (0.008 sec real, 0.011 sec wall, 14 MB, 228 syscalls)` https://eval.in/571669

Comment: well i suppose i stand corrected. your is faster, you sir, are a regex Master.

Comment: any ideas how i might speed up my method? this can be very useful for me in the future, and today.

Comment: You may want to use an array in `str_replace`, instead of calling it twice.

Comment: Good Idea, Thank you :)

Comment: Nope, Worth a shot though.
https://eval.in/571671
OK (0.016 sec real, 0.017 sec wall, 14 MB, 227 syscalls)

Comment: Even Better:
https://eval.in/571681
OK (0.008 sec real, 0.011 sec wall, 14 MB, 227 syscalls)